# Could setting the permission on these files to 600 render my OS unusable? .bash_logout, .bashrc, .profile

Tags: bash, permissions, profile, .bash-logout

I rely heavily on aliases in my `.bashrc` and it crossed my mind that I could improve my privacy / security
and somewhat harden my Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop by changing recursively the permissions of my home directory
and of its subdirectories and files (`600` for the files and `700` for the directories). And so I ran:

```
sudo chmod -R 600 /home/undoxed && sudo chmod -R u+X /home/undoxed
```

where `undoxed` is the name of my administrative user.
The recursive flag has not spared `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc`,  and`.profile`.

From what I earlier noticed when tinkering with `/etc/adduser.conf`, [setting in it](https://serverfault.com/questions/98842/useradd-with-755-permissions) `DIR_MODE=0700` along with setting `umask` in `.bashrc` to `0077`  and then adding a new user
with `useradd` results in `600` permissions of any file in the new user's home directory with the exception of: `.bash_logout` `.bashrc` `.profile`.
The said three files got `644` permissions, instead of `600` as I expected.

Why is it so that these three files were spared? Could making these files `600`, as did I manually with `chmod -R 600`, make my
OS unusable? Could there be some other consequences of these files having such permissions when compared to `644`?

So far everything seems all right but I've not rebooted after running `sudo chmod -R 600 /home/undoxed && sudo chmod -R u+X /home/undoxed`
today and I'm anxious to do so.

Comment: These files are mostly sourced instead of executed. They don't normally have the execute permission set anyway.

Comment: Never use `sudo` for files in your own directory! In this case, it simply isn't needed, but depending on the command, you could change the ownership of the files. Basically: never use sudo unless it is actually required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TL,DR: `.bash*` can be 600, but `chmod -R 600` is dangerous.

You can make your home directory accessible to only you:

```
chmod 700 ~
```

This doesn't need to be recursive. It's impossible to access a file without accessing a directory that it's in. For a directory, this means that it's impossible to access a directory without accessing its parent directory. So making a directory inaccessible (no `x` permission) makes everything under it inaccessible.

(There is one way to bypass the need to access the containing directory, which is to already have access: if a process already has a file open, it stays open, even if something changes that would now make it impossible for the process to open the file. Here “open file” includes having a directory as the process's working directory. The something that changes can be, for example, a permission change, or a move to a different directory, or the process reducing its privileges.)

There are a few circumstances in which you may need to keep parts of your home directory accessible to other users or to system services (e.g. making `.plan` accessible to `fingerd` or `~/public_html` to `httpd`). They're uncommon nowadays when most people use individual machines which don't run any public services. In such a case:

- Make your home directory traversable by everyone, but only readable and writable by you: `chmod 711 ~`
- Make the content of your home directory private: `chmod go= ~/* ~/.[!.]* ~/..?*` (non-hidden files, hidden files except `.` and `..*`, and hidden files starting with `..` other than `..` itself — ignore the error if one of these patterns doesn't match anything)
- Allow read (`r`) access, plus execute/traverse (`x`) access for directories, to the specific files and directories that need it.

These permissions allow any local user to check whether a file by a given name exists (whether `ls ~jerzy/somefile` fails with “permission denied” or “no such file or directory”) but not to list the files in your home directory.

Configuration files for programs that you use, such as bash, don't need to be public. The only processes that need to access them run on your account. You can `chmod 600 ~/.bash*` if you like. It won't make any practical difference if your home directory is only accessible to you anyway, but it won't hurt.

If you set your umask to 077, all your new files will be only accessible to you.

---

**Do not run `chmod -R 600`**. As root, this can make your system so hard to restore that reinstalling is easier. As a non-privileged user, it's easier to recover from, but still painful.

`chmod -R 600` removes execute permission from directories, and for a directory, the “execute” permission (the `x` in chmod, bit 1 in numerical values) means the ability to access file in that directory. The “read” (`r`, 4) permission only allows listing files in the directory. So `chmod -R 600 ~` forbids everyone, even you, from accessing files in your home directory. Then `chmod -R u+X ~` restores execute permissions for directories, but only if the system hasn't crashed in between.

Furthermore the sequence removes execute permission from all regular files. Some regular files need execute permission. This obviously includes any independent software that you may have installed in your home directory, and personal scripts or other programs. This can also include files that aren't generally thought of as directly executable; for example, [older versions of Ubuntu used the execute permission to indicate that certain kinds of files were trusted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file), including `.desktop` files (though [newer versions don't use this mechanism anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056591/how-do-i-mark-a-desktop-file-as-trusted-in-ubuntu-18-04)).

The sequence also makes all files writable. It can be useful to make some files read-only, for example important files that you wanted to avoid overwriting or deleting accidentally. Many version control programs make certain files read-only because they're internal state files that normally never change, or to indicate that users aren't supposed to change them directly, or to indicate that a file is locked. However, this is rarely critical.

(Incidentally, there are a few files that *must* be private, such as SSH keys. A recursive chmod in your home directory that *adds* non-user permissions would break this, and in particular could make it impossible to log into your account over SSH.)

If you want to make all your files private individually, don't change the permissions that apply to you.

```
chmod -R go= ~
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that certain standard files require specific permissions (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` needs `600`). Granted, I only know of cases where what it needs is exactly what the OP happened to have run, but as a general rule, that's one more reason why blindly running recursive chmods isn't a good idea.

Comment: I did give `700` to some of my files and directories (containing my scripts and non-critical software as cryptocurrency nodes) after having executed: `sudo chmod -R 600 /home/undoxed && sudo chmod -R u+X /home/undoxed`. For the sake of brevity I didn't mention it in the question. After the change of permissions `/home/jerzy/.cargo/bin/cargo` refuses to do anything (`Permission denied (os error 13)`) although all the files in `~/.cargo/bin` have been given `700` and `~/.cargo/` have been given `700` and all the other (nonbinary) files in `~/.cargo had been given` `600` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you decode the two patterns: `~/.[!.]*` and `~/..?*` ?

Comment: The suggestion that "It's impossible to access a file without accessing the directory that it's in" is an unfortunate approximation.  Files are not **in** directories.  Instead, directories contain *links* to files (generally hard links, but sometimes symbolic ones).  There may be multiple hard links to the same file, in different directories, and one need only reach one of them to potentially access the file.  However, the permissions on the file itself affect all access attempts.

Comment: The OP is unlikely to be dealing with multiple-hard-link situations, but a correct understanding of the true relationship between directories and (other) files is important for other matters, such as "why do I need write permission on the a file's directory to delete it, yet not on the file itself?"

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not really important here, but I've addressed your point by changing “the directory” to “a directory”.

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska I'm not familiar enough with rust tooling. Could `cargo` have a shebang? (AFAIK it shouldn't, it should be a native exectuable. Or maybe this is a shell wrapper to the real `cargo` and it's complaining about running the real `cargo`?) What does `file ~/.cargo/bin/cargo` say? What is the complete error message?

Comment: `cargo` does not have a shebang, it is a binary. `file ~/.cargo/bin/cargo
/home/jerzy/.cargo/bin/cargo`: `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, with debug_info, not stripped`. The complete error message:`error: command failed: 'cargo': Permission denied (os error 13)`